# Angular routes with mutliple router-outlets

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an angular project with multiple router-outlets. Also multiple routing modules. I figured it would have been easy to define but am having some problems. I have messed with the paths a few times but it still doesn't work.

My app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'index.html', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  { 
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./landing-page/landing-page.module').then(m => m.LandingPageModule),
  },
  { 
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  { 
    path: 'logout',
    loadChildren: () => import('./logout/logout.module').then(m => m.LogoutModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(rootRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The portion of the app.module.ts

```
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    DashboardModule,
    LoginModule,
    LogoutModule,
...   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the app.component.ts

```
  ...
  <div class="content" role="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  ...
```

landing-page-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';

const landingRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: LandingPageComponent,
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        outlet: 'side'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(landingRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LandingPageRoutingModule { }
```

landing-page.component.html

```
...
  <div class="content mat-elevation-z8">
      <router-outlet name="side"></router-outlet>
      <!-- <app-dashboard></app-dashboard> -->
  </div>
...
```

From within the landing-page.component.html, a button is clicked with the route path defined in the NavItem for

```
...
{
  displayName: 'Home',
  iconName: 'dashboard',
  route: 'dashboard',
  outlet: 'side'
},
...
```

landing-page.component.ts

```
...
  routeTo(item: NavItem) {
    debugger
    if (item.outlet == null) {
      this.router.navigate(item.route.split("/"))
    } else {
      this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { side: item.route.split("/")}}])
    }
  }
...
```

I tried admin/dashboard too with the same error.

The routes for the login and the landing page work well and as expected.

The error I am getting is

> core.mjs:7621 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002:
> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard' Error: NG04002:
> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'

As mentioned, I have set the route to admin/dashboard and left it as dashboard with the same respective error.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are importing `LandingPageRoutingModule` inside the `LandingPageModule`?

Comment: Can you set `{ enableTracing: true }` in your router config, you you can check whether the routing target is set as expected?

Comment: Yes. The LandingPageRoutingModule  was imported. I added the enableTracing to true. There is a lot of logs in the console. I will have to look through it more.

Comment: I moved the dashboard component to the app-routing.module.ts. It is updating the url to http://localhost:4200/admin/home(sidebar:dashboard) which to me implies it is working somewhat. I say somewhat as the component is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was the nesting of the dashboard component. Also the root cannot be empty "". I set it to home

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '../page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const landingRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "home",
        component: LandingPageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "dashboard",
                component: DashboardComponent,
                outlet: 'sidebar'      
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(landingRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LandingPageRoutingModule { }
```